Error: Version solving failed due to null safety in Dart Flutter project with flutter_tindercard dependency
hot to solve
give me a proper steps
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.0.  Because datingappmain depends on flutter_tindercard >=0.1.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.  The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
i want to run my app

Seems the package flutter_tindercard is not being maintained anymore. I believe you are new to Flutter and Dart. You can pull the code for the package and migrate it to null safety but I would recommend building on your own or searching for alternative packages. If you want to work using the same package, migrate it to null safety. Leaving the documentation link for null safety.
https://dart.dev/null-safety#dart-3-and-null-safety

@Abhishek jaiswal - If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

The package flutter_tindercard has not been updated in the last three years and on it's pub.dev page you can see an indication that it is not Dart 3 compatible.
Regarding null safety, there is a requirement for the package to at the very least support Dart version 2.12.
You are currently using version 0.1.1 of it (according to what you posted), but the most updated version of this package is 0.2.0.
Looking at the source of it, inside pubspec.yaml, you can see that the Dart version for version 0.2.0 is:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

which should be good for null safety.
Having said that, since this package is not maintained and is not Dart 3 compatible, I can highly suggest you either:

Find an alternative package that is maintained
Rip the code of the library and add it to your application

